# Algorithm doesn't give the answer I'm expecting in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

> http://projecteuler.net/problem=1
>
> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the
>   sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

If I change "int maxNum" to 10 or any other small number like 20, I'm getting the right answer.

But somehow when I do it with a big number like 1000, it will give me a number which I don't expect to come, I don't know why, please help.

Does it do it because it has reach the max value of an int?

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //TASK: If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
        //Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

        int multiplierA = 3;
        int multiplierB = 5;

        int maxNum = 1000;
        int i = 1;

        int deelEen = MultiplyFactory(multiplierA, i, maxNum);
        int deelTwee = MultiplyFactory(multiplierB, i, maxNum);

        int result = deelEen + deelTwee;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static int MultiplyFactory(int multiplier, int i, int maxNum)
    {
        List<int> savedNumbers = new List<int>();
        while(multiplier*i < maxNum)
        {
            savedNumbers.Add(multiplier*i);
            i++;
        }

        int answer = 0;
        foreach(int getal in savedNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(getal);
            answer = answer + getal;
        }
        savedNumbers.Clear();
        return answer;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is expected and what is unexpected output?

Comment: For starters, please don't use a method argument as a variable (I'm talking about i in MultiplyFactory)

Comment: I can't accept any answers, because I don't have enough reputation.. don't think me as an ungrateful person.

Comment: The entire point with the Euler project is that you should figure out the solution yourself, not let someone else solve it for you. Usually the Euler problems are designed so that the simplest possible solution doesn't work, and you have to think a bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to find sum of all the multiples of 3 OR 5. And what your program is doing is finding sum of all multiplers of 3 + sum of all multipliers of 5.
You can return arrays of int and then sum distinct numbers from arrays.

You can also use Linq to get distinct values from lists

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //TASK: If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
        //Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

        int multiplierA = 3;
        int multiplierB = 5;

        int maxNum = 1000;
        int i = 1;
        int result = 0;

        List<int> deelEen = MultiplyFactory(multiplierA, i, maxNum);
        List<int> deelTwee = MultiplyFactory(multiplierB, i, maxNum);

        foreach (int val in deelEen)
            result += val;

        foreach (int val in deelTwee)
            if (!deelEen.Contains(val)) result += val;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static List<int> MultiplyFactory(int multiplier, int i, int maxNum)
    {
        List<int> savedNumbers = new List<int>();
        while (multiplier * i < maxNum)
        {
            savedNumbers.Add(multiplier * i);
            i++;
        }

        return savedNumbers;

    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, thanks mate! Now I know why it wasn't working, I gave you every good stuff on this website.

Comment: -1 The entire point with the Euler project is that you should figure out the solution yourself, not let someone else solve it for you.

Comment: Ok, actually i didn't know about what Euler project is and I'd a look on this site only after I've already posted a solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you count some numbers twice.
For example you first summ 15 as dividable by 3 and then you add it as dividable by 5.

So for numbers between 1 and 20 you have

```
deelEen = 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + 15 + 18
deelTwee = 5 + 10 + 15
```

and

```
result = 3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 12 + 15 + 15 + 18
```

when the right answer is

```
result = 3 + 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 12 + 15 + 18
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I forgot that..